# JQuery - Set element attribute as his sibling text

Tags: jquery

I am trying to dinamically set the attribute `filter-by` to each Radio Button inside a page, and set the value of this attribute based on the text inside each Span Element next to them.

I came up with this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(':radio').attr('filter-by', $(this).next().text());
});
```

But it's not setting the attribute value.

This is the HTML snippet

```
<label>
   <input type="radio" filter-by="">
   <span>Text</span>
</label>
```

I'm expecting `<input type="radio" filter-by="Text">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it like this, because in your attempt `$(this)` would not refer to your `:radio`

```
$(':radio').attr({'filter-by': function() {
  return $(this).next().text()
}});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':radio').attr({'filter-by': function() {
    return $(this).next().text()
  }});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
   <input type="radio" filter-by="">
   <span>Text</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to use

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){

        $(this).attr('filter-by', $(this).next().text());

    });

});
```